# How to connect SSL VPN on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, vpn, openvpn

I have tried every openvpn configuration and setup manual.. and I failed it badly.. I just can't figure out how to connect at the end.

This vpn is provided to me by my work office.

All I have is. Vpn username & password .. gateway .. and customized port of 5 numbers in length.

I tried to connect on a Windows machine using forticlient and I succeeded.. but now I want to do it on Ubuntu and it's not that easy! Thanks.

P.S. I'm not obligated to openvpn any software will work

Answer (score 3):

As Fortinet VPN could use several VPN protocols
And as we do not know which one
-> You'd better use the Forticlient Official client for Linux & Ubuntu
Then you could export the vpn client xml configuration file from Windows that you will import to the Ubuntu client.

Find installation instructions for `18.04` here :
https://forticlient.com/repoinfo

**Install Forticlient on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**

Install gpg key

```
wget -O - https://repo.fortinet.com/repo/ubuntu/DEB-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add the following line in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.fortinet.com/repo/ubuntu/ /bionic multiverse
```

Update package lists

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install FortiClient

```
sudo apt install forticlient
```

Comment: I installed forticlient but I didn't find remote access tab like windows.. please see the screenshot
[URL] (https://photos.app.goo.gl/oQTdMvh4JCRLqQcZA)

Comment: @Ehab Shaaban click on 'Unlock settings' bottom left

Comment: I tried but it does nothing

Comment: Also I get this on settings! Is there any simplified configuration manual for openvpn or even any other software! [Screenshot URL](https://photos.app.goo.gl/iXt3JbHyZkrYRHTeA)

Answer (score 3):

Alternative to forticlient is **openfortivpn**

```
sudo apt install openfortivpn
sudo nano /etc/openfortivpn/config
```

Enter as much of the following info and save

```
host = domain.com
port = 443
username = username
password = PASSWORD
trusted-cert = asldkfjoaskdfjlasdjflsjkdflkj
```

run the vpn client

```
sudo openfortivpn
```

if `trusted-cert` was not known or used you will be prompted with the correct cert that you can put in the config file.  Rerun the `sudo openfortivpn` and you should get connected with info similar to the following

```
INFO:   Interface ppp0 is UP.
INFO:   Setting new routes...
INFO:   Adding VPN nameservers...
INFO:   Tunnel is up and running.
```

Answer (score 2):

On Linux the forticlient is split into two parts: forticlient and forticlient vpn. You need the vpn part. Note that both applications are called "forticlient" and there is much confusion. On the forticlient download page there is a link to the vpn and another link that takes you to instructions for using a repo. Us the vpn one and download a deb then use the standard install process.